# ruby 1.8 to 1.9 ruby -v shows ruby 1.9.2p0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, rvm

I want to upgrade from ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.2, I installed RVM and also ruby 1.9.2 using RVM on Ubuntu. I dont think the previous version ruby 1.8.7 was installed using RVM (not quite sure how this works :) ). 
Anyway when I type

```
ruby -v
```

I get

```
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
```

wich seems right?

but when I run my rails app and click on the *About your application’s environment* link it shows this

```
Ruby version    1.8.7 (i686-linux)
RubyGems version    1.8.10
Rack version    1.3
Rails version   3.1.1
JavaScript Runtime  Node.js (V8)
Active Record version   3.1.1
Action Pack version 3.1.1
Active Resource version 3.1.1
Action Mailer version   3.1.1
Active Support version  3.1.1
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance guys!

EDIT:

I ran rvm list and it only shows 1.9.2

```
rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ i386 ]
```

Comment: please specify more details, how do you run your application ? have you created a gemset and migrated gems from previous ruby installation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .rvmrc file to specify using necessary ruby verison.
All you need just type:

```
rvm --create --rvmrc 1.9.2@your_project_name
```

and then

```
cd .
```

After this your project must use ruby 1.9.2 and gemset your_project_name.

Comment: .rvmrc is not empty, moving aside to preserve.root@server-pc:/var/www#

Answer (score 0):

Install with RVM and when you are done run:

rvm list

then whichever you want to default your ruby to run the command below

rvm use default "name of the default ruby you want"

Comment: I ran 'rvm use default ruby-1.9.2-p0' ran the app again but when I click on 'app enviroment' it still shows 'Ruby version 1.8.7 (i686-linux)'

Comment: should be just `rvm use 1.9.2`

Comment: @Francois I just ran this on my machine, and works fine:

rvm use default ruby-1.9.2-p290

If you dont include default it would be available for just that session alone

Comment: I think the problem is that the previous version was installed without RVM, and it keeps on trying to use the old one? any way I can tell it to use the RVM version?